# ¿Cómo implementar la facturación electronica en PHP México y SAT

Tags: php

espero que se encuentren muy bien resulta que tengo mi sistema de inventario en PHP ya genero notas de remisión en PDF y también genero el formato XML que pide el SAT, lo que me falta hacer es saber como timbrarlo y que tenga validez para generar la factura electrónica, desconozco un poco el tema ya que he estado investigando y dicen que solo me faltaría conectarme con un PAC para que ellos me devuelvan la factura timbrada... Alguien tiene alguna noción de como poder hacer esto?

Comment: Tienes que contratar el servicio de timbrado según el paquete que maneje el PAC por el que decidas, ya después ellos te mandan las ligas de su web service y tal vez un manual en php para consumir el servicio (SOAP) y saber obtener los resultados del timbrado: xml, qr y cadena original

Comment: Hola @Yikarus tu ya lo has hecho? que paquete me recomiendas?

Comment: Donde estoy usamos PROFAC, el servicio ya lo habían contratado por ende los scripts de timbrado ya estaban hechos, pero les estuve metiendo mano las llamadas son muy sencillas, solo llama a las funciones del ws desde la clase soapclient que viene en php

Comment: Muy bien @Yikarus checare ese paquete, entonces recapitulando, seria primero contratar el servicio, después ellos me mandan las ligas del ws y ya me encargaría de la búsqueda del manual para hacer la conexión.

Comment: Y documentarte un poco de soap en php, consumir un webservice es muy fácil asi que no creo que tengas problemas

Comment: Muy bien @Yikarus , voy a checarlo porque ya muchos piden facturación, cualquier duda te comento va, muchas gracias amigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo que ya es un poco vieja la pregunta pero nunca esta de mas dar otras opciones.

Como lo indican anteriormente esto lo puedes hacer con proveedores de certificación, ahora si lo que se necesita es tener un poco mas de documentación al respecto por que no sabes como consumir un web service aquí va mi opción:

[Ejemplo de Timbrado de Xml en PHP](https://github.com/facturoporti/factura-electronica-Web-Service-PHP).

Puedes bajarte el código y modificarlo para hacer tus pruebas, si tienes otros requerimientos u otro tipo de proyecto hay mas ejemplos de uso:

[Repositorio de Ejemplos de Timbrado](https://github.com/facturoporti?tab=repositories)

Este servicio lo eh usado por mas de 10 años y no eh presentado problemas ademas de que el precio es muy bueno.

[Otros tipos de Timbrado](https://www.facturoporti.com.mx/timbrado/)

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [answer] para poder mejorar tus respuestas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, este servicio devuelve el xml timbrado junto con el PDF? se mira bastante llamativo el servicio